# Error when pip install tensorflowjs — Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: pip, installation, tensorflow.js

An error happens while installing tensorflowjs, it's ok to install other packages, just this package ends up with failure.

I tried to pip install --user pyspider, failed.
I upgraded pip version, still failed.
I installed tf_nightly module first and run 'pip install tensorflowjs', still failed.

```
C:\Users\Jingyi>pip install tensorflowjs
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/29/35e1aa467436ff46b98df65a08c49faaedb3429e1c512d1d90fe308040a0/tensorflowjs-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy==1.15.1 (from tensorflowjs)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/7d/f8b97d97809f184d90faf320fa8e2e7eac994844c5e6c57adbed1283e9e9/numpy-1.15.1-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting six==1.11.0 (from tensorflowjs)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tf-nightly-2.0-preview>=2.0.0.dev20190304 (from tensorflowjs)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/13/8fa7c91176d299759487d90ab201256941b43a48ecbf033a2a726f4dafce/tf_nightly_2.0_preview-2.0.0.dev20190509-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Jingyi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4ytziwpr\\tf-nightly-2.0-preview\\tf_nightly_2.0_preview-2.0.0.dev20190509.data/purelib/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/include/external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorSyclConvertToDeviceExpression.h'
```

I expect to install tensorflowjs successfully.

Comment: You're trying to install a nightly build, which might well be broken. How about you try with a stable version and see if that works?

Answer (score 1):

It was caused by windows path length limitation, you can try below:

1. Hit the Windows key, type `gpedit.msc` and press Enter.
2. Navigate to `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem`.
3. Double click the `Enable Win32 long paths` option and enable it.
4. Then restart computer and it works

[Original answer here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24835#issuecomment-453365761)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtualenv and install tensorflow within this.

First create a virtualenv:

```
python3 -m venv envname
```

Next you have to activate it

```
source envname/bin/activate
```

Then install the package

```
pip install pyspider
```

When you use a virtualenv you don't nedd the --user flag.

Using a virtualenv is always a better way when you are working locally with python projects.

Comment: I‘ve tried to install tensorflowjs in virtualenv before, but there was still the same error - 'Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:'

Comment: Can you please post all commands you are trying. Because in the code above you install tensorflowjs